# UNIX previous month and year with format YYYYMM

Tags: date, unix

I need to assign a variable with the value in the format `YYYYMM` e.g for today run the previous month values should be generated as

```
Var1 = 201607
```

Is there any in build method available? Could you share the steps to generate this?

Answer (score 3):

The trick in these cases is to subtract one month from the day 15 of the current month:

```
$ date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) - 1 month"
Fri Jul 15 00:00:00 CEST 2016
```

Then it is just a matter of using the proper format:

```
$ date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) - 1 month" "+%Y%m"
201607
```

To store the value in a var, just use the common `var=$(command)` syntax.

From [GNU Coreutils → 28.7 Relative items in date strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html):

> The fuzz in units can cause problems with relative items. For example,
>   ‘2003-07-31 -1 month’ might evaluate to 2003-07-01, because 2003-06-31
>   is an invalid date. To determine the previous month more reliably, you
>   can ask for the month before the 15th of the current month. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> $ date -R
> Thu, 31 Jul 2003 13:02:39 -0700
> $ date --date='-1 month' +'Last month was %B?'
> Last month was July?
> $ date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) -1 month" +'Last month was %B!'
> Last month was June!
> ```
>
> Also, take care when manipulating dates around clock changes such as
>   daylight saving leaps. In a few cases these have added or subtracted
>   as much as 24 hours from the clock, so it is often wise to adopt
>   universal time by setting the TZ environment variable to ‘UTC0’ before
>   embarking on calendrical calculations.